# Inconsistency in applying direct object to 勝つ

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, the verb 勝つ takes a direct object with に as

- 彼はチェス試合に勝った。He won the chess match.

and takes an indirect object with に対して as

- 彼は私に対してチェス試合に勝った。He won the chess match against me.

Now I found a sentence that seems to be inconsistent as follows.

> X: チェスにかけては、私に勝てる人がいないと自信を持っている。
>
> X': When it comes to chess, I have confidence that none can { (win against) | (beat) } me.

## Question

For the sake of consistency, why don't we use 私に対して勝てる instead of 私に勝てる in X?

Comment: 「彼は私に対してチェース試合に勝った。」←普通は「彼はチェスの試合で私に勝った」っていうような気も・・・

Comment: By the way, "chess" is always チェス. It's a short vowel, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

対して is extra and 私に勝てる is more common than 私に対して勝てる.

And 彼は、私にチェスの試合で勝った and 彼は、私とのチェスの試合に(で)勝った are natural.

Comment: Is チェス相手 also natural (dropping the の）？

Comment: I think both are used. It may be according to words. With の is natural about 試合 like 野球の試合.

Comment: @Locksleyu That's not common but possible.